# How to convert EJB 2.0 Entity to EJB 3.0 Entity when ejb-jar.xml has no primary key or table?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x

I am migrating software from EJB 2.0 to EJB 3.0. Right now, I want to annotate the Entity bean classes.

I am not sure what to do for the table and column annotations as those fields aren't in the xml. As such, I'm not even sure how the server (JBoss) is figuring out where or how to put the entity.

I added the `Entity` annotation and removed the EJB 2.0 entity interface. As of right now the code in question is of the following form...

```
@Entity(name="MyEntity")
public abstract class MyEntity
{
    private EntityContext context;

    public abstract String getField1();
    // ...
    public abstract String getFieldN();

    public abstract void setField1(String arg);
    // ...
    public abstract void setFieldN(String arg);

    public void update( String field1, ..., String fieldN)
    {
        setField1(field1);
        // ...
        setFieldN(fieldN);
    }

    public void ejbActivate()
    {
    }

    public Object ejbCreate(String field1, ..., String fieldN) throws CreateException
    {
        setField1(field1);
        // ...
        setFieldN(fieldN);

        return null;
    }

    public void ejbLoad()
    {
    }

    public void ejbPassivate()
    {
    }

    public void ejbPostCreate(String field1, ..., String fieldN)
    {
    }

    public void ejbRemove()
    {
    }

    public void ejbStore()
    {
    }

    public void setEntityContext(EntityContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public void unsetEntityContext()
    {
        context = null;
    }
}
```

and the EJB 2.0 `ejb-jar.xml` file contains an entity configuration of the form...

```
<entity>
    <display-name>MyEntity</display-name>
    <ejb-name>MyEntity</ejb-name>
    <local-home>mypackage.LocalMyEntityHome</local-home>
    <local>mypackage.LocalMyEntity</local>
    <ejb-class>mypackage.MyEntity</ejb-class>
    <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
    <prim-key-class>java.lang.Object</prim-key-class>
    <reentrant>False</reentrant>
    <cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
    <abstract-schema-name>MyEntity</abstract-schema-name>
    <cmp-field>
        <description>no description</description>
        <field-name>field1</field-name>
    </cmp-field>
    ...
    <cmp-field>
        <description>no description</description>
        <field-name>fieldN</field-name>
    </cmp-field>

    <security-identity>
        <description></description>
        <use-caller-identity></use-caller-identity>
    </security-identity>

    <query>
        <description></description>
        <query-method>
            <method-name>findByField1</method-name>
            <method-params>
                <method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
            </method-params>
       </query-method>
       <ejb-ql>select object(I) from MyEntity I where i.field1 = ?1</ejb-ql>
    </query>
    <query>
        <description></description>
        <query-method>
            <method-name>findByField2</method-name>
            <method-params>
                <method-param>java.lang.String</method-param>
            </method-params>
        </query-method>
        <ejb-ql>
        </ejb-ql
    </query>
</entity>
```

Should I include a `@Table` annotation? What about an `@ID` annotation? If yes, since I can see a table name in the query shown above, should I just do `@Table(name="MyEntity")` as the query uses?

**So, how should I annotate `MyEntity` given the apparent lack of fields in the EJB 2.0 xml file?**

In response to the comment by @Dinesh I looked up the primary key in the database. There is a table there by the display name of the entity which has a primary key of `MyEntity_upk`, and that field is not mentioned anywhere in either the config or the code.

Is that an automatically generated thing because no primary key was specified? Is that part of the EJB spec? Where does that come from, and what does it mean? Especially concerning my annotations and prepping it for EJB 3.0, what does that mean for the required annotations?

Comment: What is your primary key in the table

Comment: @Dinesh That is part of my point; the xml file has none. HMM, interesting though... I have checked because of your comment. The primary key is actually `MyEntity_upk`, a field which shows up nowhere in either the config xml or the code. Where does that come from? Something the system figures out and uses on its own because no primary key is provided?

Comment: Then you can create the entity having @Id as the MyEntity_upk and decare a method having native query in your repository class, that will use the query 
 SELECT e FROM MyEntity e where i.field1 = ?1

Comment: @Dinesh Are you suggesting I add a field to the Entity class called `MyEntity_upk`?

Comment: yes please add the field in the entity class